# JQuery add a whitespace to each new text node to prevent clumping on extraction

Tags: jquery, text, whitespace

What I do is

I want to transform

```
<div id=master>
Blah
  <span id=crap>Blah1</span>
  <div id=crap2>Blah2</div>
  <b>Blah3</b>
</div>
```

to

```
<div id=master>
Blah
  <span id=crap> Blah1 </span>
  <div id=crap2> Blah2 </div>
  <b> Blah3 </b>
</div>
```

because when I extract all the text from all elements inside master it becomes looking like this

```
BlahBlah1Blah2Blah3
```

I want it to be

```
Blah Blah1 Blah2 Blah3
```

**Edit:** In HTML if those whitespaces get removed anyways could still replace them with some symbol like

```
<div id=master>
Blah
  <span id=crap>§Blah1§</span>
  <div id=crap2>§Blah2§</div>
  <b>§Blah3§</b>
</div>
```

Comment: how to extracting all node text, can you show your code??

Comment: something like this `$("div#master").text();` but I also run other codes to clear excessive whitespaces

Comment: you can add whitespaces in each element from following code `$("*", "#master").each(function(i, o){$(o).text(' '+$(o).text()+' ')});`, but `$("div#master").text();` will return own text whitespaces and enter chars etc with inner elements text whitespaces

Comment: I use a clone of Jquery for VB.Net/C# called CSQuery and the text(); function returns all text as one huge paragraph. Sorry about that I can't use the text() method as it always returns all the text

Comment: I think the problem lies here https://github.com/jamietre/CsQuery/blob/master/source/CsQuery/CQ_jQuery/Text.cs at lines 122 ~ 140 it doesn't add any spaces

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a fix that works very fast and does the trick

```
$("div#master").html($("div#master").html().replace(/>[\s\n]*</g, "> <"));
console.log($("div#master").html());
```

https://regex101.com/r/oF5sR9/1

http://jsfiddle.net/kqgf67sa/3/

Answer (score 0):

You can put the words into an array and join it:

```
['Blah', 'Blah1', 'Blah2', 'Blah3'].join(' ');
```

That way you don't have to mess with the dom

Comment: Yeah but I don't know how to split them they come as one big word when I do $(div#master).text(); I want them already split I can't predict it.

Answer (score 0):

try a recursive function with a get text from element function:

```
window.getText = function(dom) {
$(dom)
  .contents()
  .filter(function() {
    return this.nodeType == 3 ? " " + this + " " : ""; //Node.TEXT_NODE
  });
}

window.forAllKids = function(dom, array) {
    if (dom.children.length == 0)
    {
        return array.push(getText(dom))
    }
    else
    {
        $(dom.children).each(function(){
            forAllKids($(this),array);
        })
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply:

```
$("div#master *").each(function(){
    var me = $(this);
    me.html(" " + me.html() + " "); // Even I think single space should be enougth for your goal...
});
```